# How to save opened text file in autohtokey

Tags: windows, text, scripting, autohotkey

What is the way of saving open .txt file in autohotkey. Let say you have opened text file test.txt; and you would like to close it or close it with saving any edits that you have made to that file.

I'm unable to find any method on the internet/doc. It can be a simple `#1::` hotkey. It's part of larger script and this is just for testing.

Thanks xDD

Comment: `Send, ^s` for saving the file and `Send, !{F4}` or WinClose for closing the file's active window.

Comment: Yes but it needs to test if the file had been edited because, save/dont save pop up will not be activated if file had not been changed.

Comment: If you save the file using `Send, ^s` before WinClose, no dialog box pops up.

Comment: alternatively, you can get the text conrol contents via `controlgettext` and act accordingly